# Unable to fix status bar position when blur or brightness effect is used [SwiftUI]

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, alert, navigationview

I am trying to simply make the NavigationView return to normal after either the cancel button or OK button of the custom alert view is clicked. However, the blur effect that I would like to have when the alert view is shown, seems to cause the navigation view to glitch out. I know it's the blur/brightness effect, as with both of these effects, I used trial and error and figured out that this glitch only occurs when either of them are used (brightness modifier not shown -- only the blur effect here). In the gif below, you can see that the navigation view "ignores" the status bar. How do I fix this?

[image]

My code:

```
struct Sidebar: View {
    @Binding var documents: Documents
    
    var body: some View {
        List(Folder.folders, id: \.id) { folder in
            Button {
                documents = folder.documents
            } label: {
                Text(folder.title)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Folder Directory")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                Button {
                    Folder.folders.append(Folder())
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var documents = Documents()
    @State private var showDocumentView = false
    @State private var showNewDocument = false
    @State private var showNewFolder = false
    @State private var newDocument = Document()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            NavigationView {
                Sidebar(documents: $documents)
                
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem(), GridItem()]) {
                        ForEach(documents.list, id: \.self.id) { doc in
                            FileView(doc)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Documents")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        VStack {
                            NavigationLink(isActive: $showDocumentView) {
                                NoteView(document: newDocument)
                            } label: {
                                EmptyView()
                            }

                            Button {
                                newDocument = Document()
                                showNewDocument = true
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "plus")
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .disabled(showNewDocument)
            .blur(radius: showNewDocument ? 30 : 0)
            
            TextAlertView(visibilityBool: $showNewDocument, textInput: $newDocument.title) {
                documents.list.append(newDocument)
                showDocumentView.toggle()
            }
            .opacity(showNewDocument ? 1 : 0)
            
        }
        .animation(.spring(), value: showNewDocument)
        .environmentObject(documents)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with SwiftUI. I've experienced something similar using brightness on NavigationView.

If I use `.brightness(configuringFilter ? -0.05 : 0)`, I lose the navigation bar:

[image]

If I use `.brightness(configuringFilter ? -0.05 : 0.0001)` I get the desired effect:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure it is a bug per se, as it seems consistent. The same thing happens when you set `.opacity(0)`. I think SwiftUI assumes that you meant to remove the view, not that you meant to simply make it invisible for some reason. `.onTapGesture` stops working as well. With `opacity()` is happens if you go below about 0.01. It is not, however, documented in any way.

Comment: How does setting brightness to zero could be interpreted as wanting to remove the view? If this is working as intended (i.e. not a bug), it is wildly unintuitive. Specially so considering the way brightness is explained in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/brightness(_:)

Comment: I stand corrected. Brightness doesn't affect `.onTapGesture`, etc. The others, however do.